# For zephyr for JIRA. What is difference between ZAPI and ZIP

Tags: zip, jira-zephyr

I am new to Zephyr and going through the documentation. I need to understand few basic things. I have understood this so far, that,

1. Zephyr JIRA plugin will be used to create test cases. from this plugin we will start execution of a test case (by clicking on 'E').
2. We will install zbot on a machine where actual testing will be performed. For the zbot we will have to write a ZIP which will update status of the test case under execution on JIRA.

So what is ZAPI ?? and why ZAPI if inbuilt ZIPs provided are able to update execution status directly with a single function call?

Or is it like we can use ZAPI in the custom ZIP to update more details around the current execution, like attachments etc?

I am really confused.

If ZAPI are not used inside the custom ZIPs, then where the ZAPI code will reside? how to execute that binary? Do we have to run manually or zephyr for JIRA plugin will call it ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Zephyr JIRA plugin will be used to create test cases. from this plugin we will start execution of a test case (by clicking on 'E'). - **Yes we can create test case through our automation script.**

ZAPI is an Add-ons, to access Zephyr test cases in Jira. I am able to create Test cycle, map the TEST in new test cycle through my automation script.

Let me know if you need any additional information.

Regards,